# Issue automating CSV import to an RSQLite DB

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I'm trying to automate writing CSV files to an RSQLite DB.

I am doing so by indexing `csvFiles`, which is a list of data.frame variables stored in the environment.

I can't seem to figure out why my `dbWriteTable()` code works perfectly fine when I enter it manually but not when I try to index the `name` and `value` fields.

```
### CREATE DB ###
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),"")

# FOR LOOP TO BATCH IMPORT DATA INTO DATABASE
for (i in 1:length(csvFiles)) {
  dbWriteTable(mydb,name = csvFiles[i], value = csvFiles[i], overwrite=T)
  i=i+1
}

# EXAMPLE CODE THAT SUCCESSFULLY MANUAL IMPORTS INTO mydb
dbWriteTable(mydb,"DEPARTMENT",DEPARTMENT)
```

When I run the for loop above, I'm given this error:

```
"Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'DEPARTMENT': No such file or directory

# note that 'DEPARTMENT' is the value of csvFiles[1]
```

Here's the `dput` output of `csvFiles`:

```
c("DEPARTMENT", "EMPLOYEE_PHONE", "PRODUCT", "EMPLOYEE", "SALES_ORDER_LINE", 
"SALES_ORDER", "CUSTOMER", "INVOICES", "STOCK_TOTAL")
```

I've researched this error and it seems to be related to my working directory; however, I don't really understand what to change, as I'm not even trying to manipulate files from my computer, simply data.frames already in my environment.

Please help!

Comment: You have `value = csvFiles[I]` with uppercase `I`? Also you don't need the `i=i+1`. To say more, we need something like `dput( head( csvFiles ) )`.

Comment: Hi @vaettchen, thanks for chiming in. The typo with uppercase `I` was a correction from my browser. This is not in the actual code. Any thoughts on why my for loop is not working?

Comment: I guess something is wrong with your variable `csvFiles`. If you can post the `dput()` out put? Doesn't look like a working directory error to me. The csv files have no extension (no `DEPARTMENT.csv`?

Comment: Cool function, @vaettchen. Here's the `dput()` output:
 

`c("DEPARTMENT", "EMPLOYEE_PHONE", "PRODUCT",     "EMPLOYEE", "SALES_ORDER_LINE", "SALES_ORDER", "CUSTOMER", "INVOICES", "STOCK_TOTAL")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `get()` for the *value* argument as you are passing a string value when a dataframe object is expected. Notice your manual version does not have `DEPARTMENT` quoted for *value*.

```
# FOR LOOP TO BATCH IMPORT DATA INTO DATABASE
for (i in seq_along(csvFiles)) {
  dbWriteTable(mydb,name = csvFiles[i], value = get(csvFiles[i]), overwrite=T)
}
```

Alternatively, consider building a list of named dataframes with `mget` and loop element-wise between list's names and df elements with `Map`:

```
dfs <- mget(csvfiles)

output <- Map(function(n, d) dbWriteTable(mydb, name = n, value = d, overwrite=T), names(dfs), dfs)
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you!